# open edx-ora2 customization

Tags: python, django, edx, openedx

I am recently assigned with a task to add some custom fields in openedx ORA2 xblock . I have installed openedx hawthorn release , the docker version of it . So now openedx is running well but now for customization I am searching for the ORA2 code but I did not find the code . I am preciously looking for this code https://github.com/edx/edx-ora2 in my system so that I can customize it . So can anyone help me out I am totally lost in edx, can anyone tell me where is the code location of ORA2 and how can I customize it . I know python and django but I am totally confused in edx :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docker version, you can find ORA-2 as a package in.

```
/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openassessment/
```

[image]

Comment below if you can not find.

Comment: No I didnot get any such folder . Infact via docker I just got edx-platform and other analytics , ecommerce etc.    I did the installation from here https://github.com/edx/devstack

Comment: You can see, I just added a screenshot also.

Comment: Yes , thnx got it . It was docker who make this folder in a different place . I got it now . This is an personal question , do you provide paid consultancy for edx ? If yes please revert me on ruvel@unboxinnovations.com